# Yii2 RBAC GII Integrity Constraint Violation

Tags: php, database, yii, yii2, rbac

have looked everywhere for this, finding nothing.

I am using the migration for Yii2 to add the Database tables for RBAC, they have been created fine, have double checked everything, all fine there.

I know you can use

```
$author = $auth->createRole('author');
$auth->add($author);
$auth->addChild($author, $createPost);
```

and have done fine, however, I want to have custom admin area for setting up the roles, permissions etcetera and eventually be adding group policies as well.

When I create Models and CRUD via gii to accomplish this, whenever I try to add an auth_item I get the following error

```
    Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ronbuild`.`auth_item`, CONSTRAINT `auth_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_name`) REFERENCES `auth_rule` (`name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `auth_item` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `rule_name`, `data`) VALUES ('dog', 1, '', '', '')
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1452
    [2] => Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ronbuild`.`auth_item`, CONSTRAINT `auth_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_name`) REFERENCES `auth_rule` (`name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ronbuild`.`auth_item`, CONSTRAINT `auth_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_name`) REFERENCES `auth_rule` (`name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)

in C:\wamp\www\ronbuild\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php at line 781
```

I have tried changing column details and several other bits to no avail, I wonder if anyone has come across this problem before and found a solution, as I can find nothing on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as this was torturing me, and not wanting to be held back, I began by building a seperate model for AuthItem from the floor up, and after some back and fro, I sussed this.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'type'], 'required'],
        [['type', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
        [['description', 'data'], 'string'],
        [['name', 'rule_name'], 'string', 'max' => 64]
    ];
}
```

The generated rules by Gii adds a reference to the connected foreign key via adding a rule `[['name', 'rule_name'], 'string', 'max' => 64]` and it was the mention of the `rule_name` in the rules that was bringing this error back to me all the time.

Sincerely hopes this helps anyone who has searched and found this, as there was no answer anywhere!!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem but fixed it using batchInsert() This method will properly escape the column names, and bind the values to be inserted.

Please checkout the reference http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#batchInsert()-detail

A good example how use the batchInsert() method in the following migration:

https://github.com/wartron/yii2-account-rbac-uuid/blob/master/migrations/m150823_001311_create_default_roles.php

The source code maybe look like this:

```
public function up()
{
    $columns = ['name', 'type', 'description'];
    $this->batchInsert('{{%auth_item}}', $columns, [
        [
            'admin',
            1,
            'Role Admin',
        ],
        [
            'backend',
            1,
            'Role Backend',
        ],
        [
            'user',
            1,
            'Role User',
        ],
    ]);
}
```